# How to add contrast in a text over image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

When I go on mobile size, I need the text to be readable with the provided image.

[image]

```css
#jumbotron-p {
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">PATTERN</h1>
    <p id="jumbotron-p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptate consequuntur?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @j08691 Yes, I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either try adding a text-shadow to the text inside the jumbotron this way:

```
.jumbotron.text-center h1, .jumbotron.text-center p {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

or add an overlay to the image in the background by selecting it using its class and apply an inset box-shadow to it (let's assume .jumbotron is the background image's container):

```
.jumbotron.text-center {
    box-shadow: inset 100vw 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you! :)

Comment: Works perfectly :)

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)